# vscode: rospy import error

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The env I am using is ROS Noetic and VS Code along with Pylance.

1. launching rospy nodes is working fine
2. importing rospy gives a squiggle error in VSCode.
3. Also, python syntax is not being highlighted properly. Along with that, I am also not getting auto-complete options.

I think it should be a configuration issue, but I don't know where and what I have to configure to resolve this.
Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382798/vscode:-rospy-import-error/) by [krushnal](https://answers.ros.org/users/71675/krushnal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

You have to add 2 python paths into your [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_languagespecific-editor-settings) file into VS Code.

These are the paths:
The first path is for all packages of your local workspace and the second is for the global package.

```
{
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
        "/home/<pc-name>/<ws-name>/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages",
        "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages"
    ]
}
```

If you are using CPP then you have to add the path in the c_cpp_properties.json file.

The location of setting and c_cpp_properties JSON files will be :

```
 "~/<work-space>/devel/include"
```

Just to note for **Pycharm Users**: if you are using Pycharm then give this both paths by following these steps:

1. Go to settings.
2. Project: src > Project Structure > On the right-hand side click on  + Add Content Root and locate both paths.

Try this you will be able to solve your problem and if you have any issues feel free to drop a comment.

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [krushnal](https://answers.ros.org/users/71675/krushnal/) on 2021-07-19**:
thanks a lot .... that solves it!!!